# Add label to point

Tags: ios, swift

I have followed this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/410-core-graphics-tutorial-part-2-gradients-and-contexts

I am trying to add a label over each point with the `Int` for the point, but it wont show. Adding code in the **//Draw the circles on top of graph stroke**

```
//Draw the circles on top of graph stroke
        for i in 0..<graphPoints.count {
            var point = CGPoint(x:columnXPoint(i), y:columnYPoint(graphPoints[i]))
            point.x -= Constants.circleDiameter / 2
            point.y -= Constants.circleDiameter / 2

            let circle = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(origin: point, size: CGSize(width: Constants.circleDiameter, height: Constants.circleDiameter)))
            circle.fill()

            //let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: point, size: CGSize(width: Constants.circleDiameter, height: Constants.circleDiameter)))
            let label = UILabel()
            label.frame.origin = CGPoint(x:columnXPoint(i), y:columnYPoint(graphPoints[i]))
            label.text = "TDDDDDDDE"

            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            label.textColor = UIColor.black
            self.addSubview(label)
            self.view.addSubview(label)
        }
```

Can anyone help me with adding the label? The label wont show, and I want it over the points.

Comment: Does it show the label if you call `label.needsDisplay = true` after adding it? Also, you appear to be adding it to 2 superviews. That's unlikely to work.

Answer (score 0):

Best guests, given there's not the full context. I see 3 possible reasons

1: You should replace

```
self.addSubview(label)
self.view.addSubview(label)
```

By

```
self.addSubview(label)
```

The second line will remove the label from `view` to add it to `self.view`, which might be a problem if they are different.

2: With the following line, you're telling the label to use autolayout ...but do not provide any constraint, so they might be there but not where you expected them to be.

```
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

To add constraints: [see official Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html), example below:

```
label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: aConstant).isActive = true
```

But 3: your label is initialised without a frame/an empty frame. Call `sizeToFit` on your label after having set the content, fonts, etc if you don't use autolayout. If you stick to autolayout, this point is not applicable.

And another point indirectly linked to your question: If you manage to get your code to work, you'll probably have too much labels: your code seems to be in the `draw` method, which means that you'll be instantiating new labels each time the view is rendered ...and the previous ones won't be removed. A better practice would be instanciate the labels when you load the data (if they depend on the data points), to position them in `layoutSubviews` or to skip the labels entirely and use `NSAttributedString` draw functions to render the text directly in the view.